# Building a login system using sql, php, etc

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, authentication

I am creating a login system hosted on Godaddy and following [**this**](http://cleartuts.blogspot.com/2015/01/user-registration-and-login-script-using-php-mysql.html) tutorial: . When I run the code below in phpadmin as specified by the tutorial, I get this error:

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses_crZyjAX8UT'@'localhost' to
>   database 'demo2'

Has anyone successfully created a login system using GoDaddy? Do I have a syntax error in the SQL?

```
CREATE DATABASE `dbtest` ;
CREATE TABLE `dbtest`.`users` (
`user_id` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`username` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 35 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
UNIQUE (`email`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Comment: you need to add the user cpses_crZyjAX8UT to the database demo2 under databases in your cpanel, iirc

Comment: You should really find another tutorial. This is suggesting using `ext_mysql` which is deprecated, and has you hashing passwords with `md5`. Terrible example...

Comment: I tried to add the user and was told that this user is reserved--I will look for another method.

Answer (score 0):

As Isaac said, you need to add that user to the database in cPanel. When doing so, be sure to check the boxes that allow access to the CREATE function.